Salesforce|Lightning Experience: Creating and Embedding a Visual_Force_Page in a Dashboard (Lightning Experience)
I had the Idea of creating a dashboard with a table that exits in a VFP (Visual Force Page) in it.
I want my VFP show up on a dashboard. But is it possible at all in Lightning Experience or is it just a classic thing?
Is it possible at all, to show something like a html-based-table in dashboards? (Which A VFP is kind of HTML)
Also, is there maybe a better Idea, to achieve the same thing?
Since this started as a workaround, it does not have to become very complicated or it defeats its own purpose.

Plz clarify what is VFP. I

VFP (Visual Force Page) is a kind of html document, that retrieves data from a Apex class (controler).
The whole problem is about the SOQL, which Salesforce is based on and the incompatibility of "classic" dokuments like the VFP and the newer lightning compontents, like the reports, that you can create and view over dashboards.
I basicly had the idea to html join some querys, which works fine, but then i also need to convert the product in a "lightning compontent".
(If any of this is different to your experience, pls be sure to correct me.)
